# Oracle OR statement

Tags: oracle

I need to select records where the ACTUAL_END_DATE is null or has a date that is no older than 90 days at the point of running the query.

This is what I have tried using but it is returning too many records, it seems to be ignoring the OR clause

```
CU.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 'C' AND ((C.ACTUAL_END_DATE IS NULL) OR (C.ACTUAL_END_DATE <= (SYSDATE + 90)))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if you gave an example of a record that should not have been returned, but was.

That being said:

"no older than 90 days at the point of running the query."

Would indicate you want items where SYSDATE - ACTUAL_END_DATE is /less than or equal/ to 90, not greater than or equal to 90.

As written, presuming no end dates are in the future, you are getting all records that have already ended (since any end date will be less than or equal to SYSDATE, and the 90 becomes superfluous).

If this is the case, what you want is:

```
CU.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 'C' AND ((C.ACTUAL_END_DATE IS NULL) OR (C.ACTUAL_END_DATE >= (SYSDATE - 90)))
```